# How does the TestContext name is relevant in given code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I am using MicrosoftTestTools. I have a class A containing [TestMethod] and [ClassInitialize].

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
{
    Setup(context);
}
```

Definition for Setup is present in Class B(Baseclass of class A).

```
   public static void Setup(TestContext context)
    {
something
    }
```

[TestCleanUp] is present in Class B.

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanUp()
{    
        if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed){}

}
```

To get the TestContext in TestCleanUp method I have created a property like below in class B.

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

It worked fine. But when I changed the declaration like ,

```
public `TestContext CurrentContext{ get; set; }`
```

So function like

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanUp()
{ 
if (CurrentContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed){}
}
```

CurrentContext is null. How does the property work here? This works only when the name is TestContext. I am naive to C# programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have noticed that you don't assign `TestContext` property yourself, but somehow it gets its value. How it gets a value? Test framework assigns it. How it finds that property? It looks for a property named `TestContext` of type `TestContext`. So when you change the name - it cannot find it any more and cannot assign a value, so it remains null.

You can read more about this class in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699(v=vs.80).aspx). Relevant part for this question is:

> When you run a unit test, you are automatically provided with a
>   concrete instance of the TestContext type, *if the test class that
>   contains your unit test method has a TestContext property defined*.